# What is "ping pong" in the context of graphics rendering?

Tags: opengl, rendering, blending, rendertargets, multiple-render-targets

I have to render a scene, once per light, and blend the result of the various passes. I heard and read that one way to increase performances and render targets to use would be *ping pong*.

I'm new to this context. What does this mean in terms of render targets + blending?

Comment: It's "ping pong," referring to the back and forth nature. This question isn't very specific. Look for tutorials about multiple buffering, etc. If you get stuck, as a specific question about what you need help with here.

Answer (score 1):

"Ping pong is a technique to alternately use the output of a given rendering pass as input in the next one."

(Example: http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis565/fbo.htm)